# Clonar repositorio remoto de git hasta cierto commit

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Tengo un proyecto almacenado en un respositorio de [bitbucket](/questions/tagged/bitbucket) y necesito clonarlo hasta cierto commit, he intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
git clone https://<usuario>@bitbucket.org/<repositorio> id_commit
```

Pero no ha funcionado. **¿Como puedo clonar un repositorio hasta un commit en especifico?**

Comment: Creo que seria mas facil si clonas el repositorio y posteriormente haces una `git checkout id_commit`

Comment: @IvanBotero esa es la respuesta correcta :) te animás a postearla como respuesta en vez de comentario? si no, la escribo yo... peero, vos llegaste primero así que te corresponde ;)

Comment: @g3rv4 Hecho, muchas gracias por el comentario, ya he realizado la respuesta. Espero que le ayude al OP.

Comment: @IvanBotero y si no ayuda al OP, a los miles que vengan detrás con la misma pregunta :)

Comment: @g3rv4 Por eso siempre escribo mis respuestas explicando lo mejor posible :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Tener en cuenta

Debemos tener en cuenta que al realizar una **clonación de un repositorio** remoto de [git](/questions/tagged/git), se **descarga el repositorio completo**, lo cual no necesariamente puede limitar el hecho de **regresar a algún commit** en específico.

---

## ¿Cómo lo hacemos?

Voy a explicar un ejemplo con un repositorio que he creado en [bitbucket](/questions/tagged/bitbucket).

#### Primero

**Realizamos la clonación** del repositorio:

```
git clone https://usuario@bitbucket.org/usuario/repositorio.git
```

Habiendo hecho esto, **tendremos una carpeta** con el nombre de nuestro repositorio.

```
cd repositorio/
```

Estando dentro de dicho directorio, **obtenemos el listado de commits**.

```
git log
```

Obteniendo algo como esto:

```
commit a0f4ae240b8c786b85b90414ff89418d057f4528
Author: Fulano de tal <fulano.detal@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 27 11:50:27 2017 -0500

    Tercer Commit

commit 7a080414fff18f4a452c7885b9d08b5894e240b6
Author: Fulano de tal <fulano.detal@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 27 11:42:50 2017 -0500

    Segundo Commit

commit f18f4a4528b85b9d057a080414ff894e240bc786
Author: Fulano de tal <fulano.detal@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 27 11:40:53 2017 -0500

    Primer Commit
```

Debemos fijarnos en el valor de *commit*, aquel que es un `hash`. Este es el **identificador del commit**.

#### Entonces

Basta obtener el identificador del commit  al cual queremos regresar nuestro código **(e.j: *7a080414fff18f4a452c7885b9d08b5894e240b6*)**, en este caso, para nuestro segundo commit. Y ejecutamos el siguiente comando:

```
git checkout 7a080414fff18f4a452c7885b9d08b5894e240b6
```

Y voilà!

Nuestro repositorio ha regresado a como estaba cuando se realizó el commit.

Answer (score -3):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

1.- Clonar el repositorio desde el branch deseado

```
git clone https://<usuario>@bitbucket.org/<repositorio> id_commit
```

2.- Recuperar el commit especifico

```
git fetch origin <sha1-del-commit>
```

3.- Resetear el branch hasta el commit deseado

```
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Cabe aclarar que id_commit lo unico que hara sera crear una carpeta y dejaria el repositorio en id_commit/repositorio.

Comment: Sugerir hacer `git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD` me parece una mala idea... el OP no dijo que quería modificar la historia, esto puede generarle muchos dolores de cabeza (además de lo que dijo @IvanBotero... el `id_commit` se usaría como directorio)